# How to retry a POST call based on response code, how and what are the ways to capture response data in Apache Jmeter?

Tags: api, jmeter

1) Applying retry POST/auth based on response status if its 302, call GET/token and all other otherwise exit? Want to atleast retry POST call for 3 times.

Have  While controller+CSV data set with username,password and accountid with 5 different test users.

Have a -Thread group
         |-GET/auth
         |POST/auth
         |GET/token
         |GET/profile/profileid
         |GET/profileid/address

2)How and ways to Capture profileid from response of GET call?Don't want to save it into CSV. But more prefer into console.

Comment: I tried adding this way but need help to improve

Comment: In Threadgroup>have while the controller to loop counter<5  > have POST call with a)Result status handler set to :continue b) Response code assertion for 302 status code. Should i add any sampler here to verify retrying for 3 times and then go to next call? Should all further calls down POST call be at same node or child level? Need help.